# How to show a continuous random variable with even pdf also has a even moment generating function?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, even-and-odd-functions

The moment generating function is

$M_X(t)=$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x) dx$ if X is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: change of variables $u = -x$ in the integral.

Comment: OK I've got it..... sorry forget to transform the pdf of x into pdf of y....